# Timers.Timer continue works after Interval exceeded

Tags: c#, timer, system.timers.timer

I declare list of Timers like this:

```
private List<System.Timers.Timer> dio_timers = new List<System.Timers.Timer>();
```

And fill list of timers in a loop:

```
private void DIOTimerControl()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < PrinterNumber; i++)
    {
        dio_timers.Add(new System.Timers.Timer()
        {
            Interval = Convert.ToDouble(lst_PrinterStruct[i].DIOCountWindow),
            AutoReset = false,
        });

        dio_timers[i].Elapsed += OnTimerOutEvent;

        File.AppendAllText("PackingLogTimer.txt", "Timer " + i.ToString() + " Added at: " 
            + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString() + "; Timer duration: " 
            + Convert.ToDouble(lst_PrinterStruct[i].DIOCountWindow).ToString() + "\r\n");
    }
}


private void OnTimerOutEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    int index = dio_timers.IndexOf((System.Timers.Timer)source);
    dio_timers[index].Stop();
    File.AppendAllText("PackingLogTimer.txt", "Date: " 
        + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString() + "; Timer " 
        + index.ToString() + " stops at: " + e.SignalTime.ToString() + "\r\n");
}
```

And start timers in another function:

```
private void TimerStart()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < PrinterNumber; i++)
    {
        dio_timers[i].Start();
        File.AppendAllText("PackingLogTimer.txt", "Timer " + i.ToString() 
            + " Started at: " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString() 
            + "; Timer duration: " 
            + Convert.ToDouble(lst_PrinterStruct[i].DIOCountWindow).ToString() + "\r\n");
    }
}
```

When timers finished, I see next data in text file

> Timer 0 Added at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 2000
>   Timer 1 Added at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 2000
>   Timer 2 Added at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 2000
>   Timer 3 Added at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 2000
>   Timer 4 Added at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 2000
>   Timer 5 Added at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 4000
>   Timer 6 Added at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 2000
>   Timer 7 Added at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 2000
>   Timer 8 Added at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 3000
>   Timer 9 Added at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 5000
>   Timer 10 Added at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 4000
>   Timer 11 Added at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 8000
>   
>   Timer 0 Started at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 2000
>   Timer 1 Started at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 2000
>   Timer 2 Started at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 2000
>   Timer 3 Started at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 2000
>   Timer 4 Started at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 2000
>   Timer 5 Started at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 4000
>   Timer 6 Started at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 2000
>   Timer 7 Started at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 2000
>   Timer 8 Started at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 3000
>   Timer 9 Started at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 5000
>   Timer 10 Started at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 4000
>   Timer 11 Started at: 17.04.2019 20:04:13; Timer duration: 8000
>   
>   Date: 17.04.2019 20:04:15; Timer 7 stops at: 17.04.2019 20:04:15
>   Date: 17.04.2019 20:04:16; Timer 8 stops at: 17.04.2019 20:04:16
>   Date: 17.04.2019 20:04:17; Timer 10 stops at: 17.04.2019 20:04:17
>   Date: 17.04.2019 20:04:18; Timer 9 stops at: 17.04.2019 20:04:18
>   Date: 17.04.2019 20:04:21; Timer 11 stops at: 17.04.2019 20:04:21
>   Date: 17.04.2019 20:04:26; Timer 6 stops at: 17.04.2019 20:04:26
>   Date: 17.04.2019 20:04:26; Timer 4 stops at: 17.04.2019 20:04:26
>   Date: 17.04.2019 20:04:26; Timer 3 stops at: 17.04.2019 20:04:26
>   Date: 17.04.2019 20:04:26; Timer 2 stops at: 17.04.2019 20:04:26
>   Date: 17.04.2019 20:04:26; Timer 1 stops at: 17.04.2019 20:04:26
>   Date: 17.04.2019 20:04:26; Timer 0 stops at: 17.04.2019 20:04:26
>   Date: 17.04.2019 20:04:26; Timer 5 stops at: 17.04.2019 20:04:26

Why do timers with 2 second intervals work about 13 seconds and stop last? Where is my error?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2) you can read that if synchronization object is not defined the `Elapsed` event is handled by a `ThreadPool` which can add some time for that event to fire because of threads initialization, dispatching to desired thread etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Ok. Int this case what object should be defined as "synchronization object"? And how? Can you provide a code?

Comment: Reading [referencesource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/services/timers/system/timers/Timer.cs,215) there's a public property called `SynchronizingObject`.

Comment: I know adout this property. I asked about another: SynchronizingObject = what_should_be here?

Comment: You should put any object that contains [`ISynchronizeInvoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2). You can create one by yourself or use one of the objects that derrives from it, one of which is 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'. More on how to implement this interface you can find [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2008/01/07/isynchronizeinvoke-now/)

Comment: Mateusz, I'm never worked with  ISynchronizeInvoke. Can I ask you about share example? And I using WPF, not Win Forms.

Comment: I've edited my comment, there's a link to example on msdn blog. If that won't help I will create working example.

Comment: Create please, if it possible. According to my example, if it possible also. Because I don't understand how to implement  ISynchronizeInvoke.

Comment: I'd recommend using a `DispatchTimer` if you are using WPF.  You don't have to worry about threads, or dispatching when you use it, it handles all that for you.

Comment: Can I ask you share example?